# How to achieve this typing & deleting effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’d like to replicate this website’s typing & deleting effect: http://www.cantercompanies.com.

I’ve been trying to figure this out using code blocks, HTML, CSS, and JS. However, I can’t seem to get this to work after hours and days of trying.

It’s obviously on my end, as I am fairly new to coding.

I really want this exact typing & deleting effect with blinking cursor.  I of course will be using my own logo and fixed text, but need some guidance and help to replicate Canter's example above in the link provided… :-)

Comment: what specifically have you tried?  where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I tried from codepen... copy and pasted HTML, CSS, but I am having trouble with JS.  I am new and don't know exactly what to do with the JS code.

Comment: Would you have the Codepen to hand, so readers can see it? Please edit it into your question.

Comment: [This link](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) was provided in a (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any library,

**HTML**

```
  <div class="flex">
    <p class="header-sub-title" id="word"></p><p class="header-sub-title blink">|</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto';
html, body {
    background-color: #000;
}
h2, a, p {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-decoration: none;
}
p>a {
    color: #fd084a;
}
.blink {
  animation: blink 0.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink{
  to { opacity: .0; }
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.header-sub-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0.1em;
}
```

**JS**

```
const words = ["CSS3.", "HTML5.", "javascript."];
let i = 0;
let timer;

function typingEffect() {
    let word = words[i].split("");
    var loopTyping = function() {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('word').innerHTML += word.shift();
        } else {
            deletingEffect();
            return false;
        };
        timer = setTimeout(loopTyping, 500);
    };
    loopTyping();
};

function deletingEffect() {
    let word = words[i].split("");
    var loopDeleting = function() {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            word.pop();
            document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = word.join("");
        } else {
            if (words.length > (i + 1)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            };
            typingEffect();
            return false;
        };
        timer = setTimeout(loopDeleting, 200);
    };
    loopDeleting();
};

typingEffect();
```

**Reference**:https://codepen.io/haaswill/pen/VKzXvZ

Comment: So, I copy and pasted the HTML in the Code Block.  Then I copy and pasted the CSS in Custom CSS (it got the cursor blinking on page)... but where do I put the JS?  I've tried placing this in the Code Block (didn't work) and then tried Custom CSS (didn't work) is there a special place to put JS?  Thanks again man!

Comment: Create a script file, like script.js or index.js and place your JS code there and reference the script file in your .html file. Or if you find that difficult, you can embed the code in your HTML using script tag. I have created a demo for you here https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5cubrf

Comment: Thank you, Rathnakara.  I got a "script disabled" and a "embedded script box" ... However, I am very new and trying to build my website myself, and this just may be over my head with the JS part as I don't know what I am doing with that.  I truly appreciate your help so far and I understand if you don't wanna waste your time on this.